# Row size doesn't exceed for VarChar

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-5.7

**My table**:

```
create table test( pk bigint primary key,
value1 varchar(255),
value2 varchar(255),
value3 varchar(255),
value4 varchar(255),
value5 varchar(255),
value6 varchar(255),
value7 varchar(255),
value8 varchar(255),
value9 varchar(255),
value10 varchar(255),
value11 varchar(255),
);
```

**Insert Query**:

```
insert into test values(1, '‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱','‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱‱');
```

My page size is `16KB`. So a row in my table can contain max of `8192bytes`(i.e. `8KB`).

I have created 11 `VARCHAR` column(each 255 characters), where these 11 columns can hold max of `255*11 = 2805` characters.

If I store a `2805 - 3byte` characters, it will take (`255*11*3`) = `8415bytes` which exceeds the limit of max row size(`8192bytes`).

Now I tried to insert the above single row query, which has `8415bytes` data. But my `MYSQL` didn't throw error which accepted that insert query.

```
3 byte character - ‱

Row Format - DYNAMIC

Collation - UTF8mb3

Character set - utf8_general_ci

Mysql - 5.7
```

> **Update**: Same thing is happening for CHAR column too(changed VarChar to Char), which is Fixed-length column.

Comment: Mysql varchar can be 1-byte or 2 byte  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-varchar/  . Do you have to use varchar type in this way for some particoular reason ? Because there is also BLOB type wich work nice .

Comment: @BUcorp - I am skeptical of that tutorial website -- I don't see any clue of ENGINEs that are involved, nor version of MySQL/MariaDB.  There have been several changes relating to the OP's question over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SHADOW said for `VARHCAR` columns

> If a row is less than half a page long, all of it is stored locally within the page. If it exceeds half a page, variable-length columns are chosen for external off-page storage until the row fits within half a page

For `CHAR` columns

> InnoDB encodes fixed-length fields greater than or equal to 768 bytes in length as variable-length fields, which can be stored off-page. For example, a CHAR(255) column can exceed 768 bytes if the maximum byte length of the character set is greater than 3, as it is with utf8mb4.
>   https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,645115,645215#msg-645215

Where mysql internally converts fixed-length fields to variable-length fields
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstood the innodb row size limit description. Quote from the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html#innodb-maximums-minimums) (emphasis is mine):

> The maximum row length, **except for variable-length columns** (VARBINARY, **VARCHAR**, BLOB and TEXT), is slightly less than half of a page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB page sizes. For example, the maximum row length for the default innodb_page_size of 16KB is about 8000 bytes.
> ...
>
> If a row is less than half a page long, all of it is stored locally within the page. **If it exceeds half a page, variable-length columns are chosen for external off-page storage until the row fits within half a page**, as described in Section 14.12.2, “File Space Management”.

Since your fields are varchar (a variable length fiekd type), the data above the half-page size limit is simply stored in an other, off-page location, hence your sql statement is correct.

**edit**

For `char` fields the behaviour depends on the row format and the charater set used.

A `char` field's length is fixed in terms of number of characters, but depending on the character set, the byte length may be either fixed (e.g. latin1 is fixed 1 byte / character), or variable (e.g. utf8mb3 is variable length 1-3 bytes / character).

For `compact` row format the character set is irrelevant, you get an error message if the max possible byte length exceeds the data page limit derived from the page size configuration when you want to create the table.

For `dynamic` row format, if the character set is fixed length and the byte length exceeds the data page limit, then you get an error when you want to create the table. However, if the character set is variable length, then the data gets stored in the overflow pages.

Comment: I have a doubt then why they arr imposing Row Size Limits for VARCHAR column. Check the Row Size Limit Examples in the url https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/column-count-limit.html. . Please give brief description about this. And which columns will be stored in off page for my case as you said.

Comment: 1) the innodb example in your link uses `char` data type, which is not dynamic, it is fixed length. You used `varchar` data type, which is variable length. 2) No clue which columns will be stored off the page. Check out Section 14.12.2, “File Space Management” of the mysql manual, perhaps that will give you the answer.

Comment: They used VarChar too please check, it will really be helpful. `CREATE TABLE t (a VARCHAR(10000), b VARCHAR(10000),
       c VARCHAR(10000), d VARCHAR(10000), e VARCHAR(10000),
       f VARCHAR(10000), g VARCHAR(6000)) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1;
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used 
table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns 
to TEXT or BLOBs `

Comment: that example you reference demonstrates the **MySQL maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes**, not the innodb half page limit. Again, you are mixing things up.

Comment: I tried the same process changing VarChar(255) to Char(255). As you said ```If it exceeds half a page, variable-length columns are chosen for external off-page storage until the row fits within half a page``` it is only applicable for variable length columns not fixed length columns(char). Why is it inserting without any issue. Any idea

Comment: Probably because of silent coumn specification change. Mysql converts char fields longer than a few of characters to varchar.

Comment: Or just the size of the data you are inserting is less than you calculated.

Comment: I calculated the size correctly and inserted. And for silent column change it is not mentioned these type of changes done silently.

Comment: There are 4 different `ROW_FORMAT` in InnoDB; they handle off-record storage differently.

Comment: "Off page" (aka "off-record") requires a 'pointer' in the main record.  That is, depending on `ROW_FORMAT`, 767+20 bytes or 20 bytes.  The latter constrains a row to have no more than about 400 varchars.

Comment: Does anyone have a valid reference to the 65KB limit?  I think it is an old "wives tale".

Comment: `CHAR` is no longer truely fixed-length.  (It used to be.)  It is _effectively_ fixed length because trailing spaces are provided.

Comment: If you inserted English text into a `CHAR .. CHARSET utf8`, the `*3` goes away.  (See my previous comment.)

Comment: @RickJames here you go: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits

Comment: @RickJames Check out my answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Internally, for **variable-length character sets such as utf8mb3 and utf8mb4,** InnoDB attempts to store CHAR(N) in N bytes by trimming trailing spaces. If the byte length of a CHAR(N) column value exceeds N bytes, trailing spaces are trimmed to a minimum of the column value byte length. The maximum length of a CHAR(N) column is the maximum character byte length × N.
>
> A minimum of N bytes is reserved for CHAR(N). Reserving the minimum space N in many cases enables column updates to be done in place without causing index page fragmentation. By comparison, CHAR(N) columns occupy the maximum character byte length × N when using the REDUNDANT row format.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-compact-row-format-characteristics

The above refers to `ROW_FORMAT` = COMPACT, DYNAMIC, and COMPRESSED (before compression).  And it is talking about **on-page** storage of **CHAR**.